# Python: Displaying a binary array as image

Tags: python

I have a mask image which is technically a matrix full of True/False values. I would like to view this as an image. First, I converted it into a binary array with (`astype(np.uint8)`)

```
print('Part Mask', p['masks'][class_id].astype(np.uint8))
```

but I still can't view it as an image under Python notebook. OpenCV goes crazy and crashes the kernel.

Does anyone know how to view such a structure as an image on Python notebook without crashing the kernel?

```
    [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
     ...
     [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

or this would work as well ():

```
[[False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 ...
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]
 [False False False ... False False False]]
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I cannot copy paste the whole code here but basically I have a prediction tensor `p`, and `p[masks][class_id]` is what I want to visualize (showing the mask of each class).

```
enumerator = 0
# run through the instances
for class_id in p['class_ids']:
    #print('Image:', image) # the original input image
    #print('Mask:', merged_mask) # whole masked image
    print('ID: ', class_names[class_id] + str(enumerator))
    #print('Outline Poses: ', ) # mask boundary coordinates
    #print('Pose:',) # mask center coordinates
    print('Part Mask', p['masks'][class_id].astype(np.uint8)) # how to visualize this as an image?
    print('Confidence: ', p['scores'][class_id])
    print('BB: ', p['rois'][class_id]) # get the BB
    print('--------------------------')
    enumerator = enumerator + 1
```

[image]

P.S: Matplotlib does not work either. This is the kind of image I get when I try to print:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried matplotlib?

Comment: Got another error with that, but perhaps it was because of something else, could you suggest a way with matplotlib?

Comment: Please do not even think of pasting the whole code here. Create a [mcve] instead.

Comment: Not sure if this was a bot answer or not @Goyo. I said myself I cannot paste the code here, you don't need to link me that page.

Comment: No, it's not. But you do not need to care, just think whether the advice makes sense or not. You have an example of matplotlib working with sample data. It does not work with your data but we don't know why. Knowing that it comes from a masked prediction tensor does not help. Having an actual hardcoded sample does.

Comment: My point is that when someone asks you to "post your code" they do not mean "the whole code".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matplotlib should work for you:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


image = np.eye(10)
binary = image > 0
plt.imshow(binary)
plt.show()
```

With result:

[image]

**Edit:**
Your image is of shape `(510,7)`, what you got above is exactly what you should expect:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


image = np.eye(510)[:,:7]
binary = image > 0
plt.imshow(binary)
plt.show()
```

Results: 
[image]

Comment: Post your code, This seems like a problem with the notebook your using, the figure does not get the size it should get.

Comment: I don't think what you created with`np.eye()` there is the same with my data though. Mine is `(510, 7) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: Probaly not, but `binary = image > 0` create a binary array which I am using to plot. The content of the array does not matter, as long as it is Binary.

Comment: @Schütze your image looks ok to me for an array of that shape. What else do you expect?

Comment: @Schütze This is exactly what you should expect. It's working fine.

Comment: So if this is not fine (doesn't look like a mask of anything), it means the array is messed up?

Comment: You have an image of `(510,7)`, it will look like a very narrow rectangle, I don't know if it is messed up, as we do not know what is the expected result.

Comment: There is no way  that it could be any mask in the masked image. See my edit.

Comment: `image(binary)` is a very useful function in R to visualize NAs. Is there no way to scale the axes on the second plot in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may use [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io)

```py
from PIL import Image

data = [...]

width = len(data[0])
height = len(data)

output_image = Image.new(mode='1', size=(width, height))

for x in range(height):
    for y in range(width):
        pixel_value = data[x][y]
        output_image.putpixel((x,y), pixel_value)


output_image
```

Output is such this image ->[image: Click and zoom the image to pixels]<-
[Click and zoom the image to pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHrTn.png) using the following data:

`data =  [[0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,1], [1,1,1,0], [0,1,1,0]]`

Comment: Gave an error at `output_image.putpixel((x,y), pixel_value)` saying `SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple`

Comment: What version of PIL you use ?

Comment: Version I have is 5.1.0

Comment: I have version 5.3.0 and python3.6 , and all works. Try to update PIL version